# Assessing code for systems modeling and analysis

Tags: algorithm, matlab, system, analysis, modeling

I'm currently studying some practice coding questions for a systems modeling and analysis course. The code is as follows:

```
home

num_samples = 20;
agents = nan(1,num_samples); %Create a new empty array

for i=1:num_samples
    agents(i) = rand(1); %random number between 0 and 1
end

for time=1:1000
    for current=1:num_samples
        x = 0.0;
        for other=1:num_samples
            x = x+agents(other);
        end

        pivot = x/num_samples;
        rtmp = rand(1);
        if agents(current) < pivot
            agents(current) = agents(current)+rtmp;
        else
            agents(current) = agents(current)-rtmp;
        end

    end
end
```

I am expected to answer the following questions only by READING the code, not actually running it:

1. How do the agents affect one another?
2. What long-term behaviors will they show (or not show)?
3. Name one system this model could (roughly) represent.

Having some trouble figuring out what this code is actually doing. I think its mainly the `pivot` variable that's throwing me off. By the time `pivot` is calculated, `x` represents the cumulative sum of `agents`, so I dont really know what dividing it by its length (`num_samples=20`) actually gives you. How the `agents` affect one another depends on what `pivot` is doing, I think, and that should certainly help me answer at least the first two questions right?

Any insight would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? `agents` is initialized with 100 columns, but only the first column is ever accessed. `pivot` is the mean value of samples.

Comment: Shoot, you're totally right, I copied the code incorrectly. Just updated it -- sorry about that. pivot being the mean makes sense, but how do agents on a given iteration of time affect one another? And is there any predictable long term behavior?

Comment: It looks like the system will take a random walk, with individual agents being randomly pulled towards the average of the group at each time step. Think of a bunch of people doing a drunkard's walk as a group.